# SQL Server - Row Number based on one col, and distinct values of another col

Tags: sql-server

I have data which looks like this

```
CustomerID  OrderID   Date          Value
100411      00543     06/11/2013    90.75
100411      00543     06/11/2013    81.75
100411      00560     06/11/2013    80.00
100413      00580     06/11/2013    82.34
```

I can assign a row number to rank the orders per customer:

```
    SELECT CustomerID, OrderID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY Date) [PurchaseNumber]
    FROM CustomerOrders
```

Which gives me:

```
CustomerID  OrderID   PurchaseNumber
100411      00543     1
100411      00543     2
100411      00560     3
100413      00580     1
```

If I need my rank to group orders with the same OrderID, how might I achieve the following output?

```
CustomerID  OrderID   PurchaseNumber
100411      00543     1
100411      00560     2
100413      00580     1
```

(OrderID: 00543 is grouped into just 1 purchase)

Comment: Don't use Row_number use `dense_rank()` and add add orderID to the partition.  or use order number but use an inline view to select distinct cusotmerID, OrderID first then keep your existing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aggregating, `order by OrderId`

```
select 
    CustomerId
  , OrderId
  , [PurchaseNumber] = row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by OrderId) 
  , Value = sum(Value)
from CustomerOrders
group by CustomerId, OrderId
```

returns:

```
+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
| CustomerId | OrderId | PurchaseNumber | Value  |
+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
|     100411 |   00543 |              1 | 172,50 |
|     100411 |   00560 |              2 | 80,00  |
|     100413 |   00580 |              1 | 82,34  |
+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
```

If you are not aggregating, use [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
select 
    CustomerId
  , OrderId
  , [PurchaseNumber] = dense_rank() over (partition by CustomerId order by OrderId) 
  , Value
from CustomerOrders
```

returns:

```
+------------+---------+----------------+-------+
| CustomerId | OrderId | PurchaseNumber | Value |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------+
|     100411 |   00543 |              1 | 90,75 |
|     100411 |   00543 |              1 | 81,75 |
|     100411 |   00560 |              2 | 80,00 |
|     100413 |   00580 |              1 | 82,34 |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------+
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/OAUJ25435